# remoteMessage.getData() return null in firbase notif in android

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

when i send data with json to android app the object data always return null.
this is my json

```
{

"to":"d2CSN_O-QpiWvuZxo4peZx:APA91bHafmZcG2ecOcB1NMtlLw1nsY3FWSRhSPLBmMxyZbzdMt30I0tQPocaMWnSWpNTjy0TYeP_hxZWHVP-KLRCj9Eoc7-LJHyr75dTyr0VUS25EB8DH4CFrlYvurcKENuWKBaTSZ6g",
"notification":{
  "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
  "body":"great match!"
},
"data" : {
  "Nick" : "Mario",
  "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
}
```

}

and this is my FirebaseMessagingService the notification json is correct but data allways return null

```
public class CustomMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
NotificationManager notificationManager;
Notification notification;
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    if (remoteMessage != null){
        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();


        generateNotification(title , message);

        Log.e("NOTIFICATION", title + " " + message);

    }

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){
        String value = remoteMessage.getData().get("value");
        Log.e(TAG, "onMessageReceived: "+ value );
    }
}
```

}